# Jlabel Extra Clickable Space

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, windowbuilder

I create buttons using jlabels, so I can make a image into sort of a button. The only problem is, is that jlabels are square, therfore if i click somewhere within the square where the picture is not contained, it still runs the jlabel.MouseClickEvent. Is there any fix for this, or another component that i could use?

Ex. If i click [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=circle&safe=strict&tbm=isch&imgil=kQUw5ujhIQVpBM%253A%253BzrK76wAy566TxM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.glumagazine.com%25252Fheresies%25252Fopen%25252Fher-circle%25252F&source=iu&pf=m&fir=kQUw5ujhIQVpBM%253A%252CzrK76wAy566TxM%252C_&usg=__4kLJBZFsWkJUEX4cq6UOH4WX_Wc%3D&biw=1920&bih=971&ved=0ahUKEwjut-yMxLLLAhXMSiYKHQ3hABMQyjcINg&ei=_obfVu7AJ8yVmQGNwoOYAQ#imgrc=NWPJFNyTT3hunM%3A) on the corner where the circle is not showing, but the square is still there, then the event fires.

Any fixes/different components to use? Thanks!

Comment: Note that I made sure the background was transparent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just using simple Shapes for the images then you might be able to use the `Shape Component` found in [Playing With Shapes](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/05/13/playing-with-shapes/).

The `ShapeComponent` will only respond to mouse events within the bounds of the Shape.

Otherwise the solution is to override the `contains(...)` method of your JLabel to check if the mouse point is in the bounds of your image, or in your case if the pixel at that location is not transparent.

Comment: @CrazedCoder, I was just in the middle of adding a comment about overriding the `contains(...)` method to check for non-transparent pixels.